# New release of CiviVolunteer or patch for DB Error: unknown error Return to home page

Tags: civivolunteer

Is there a new release for CiviVolunteer yet or at least how can I patch the 
"DB Error: unknown error Return to home page" error.

After doing the modification to both files:

May 07 08:39:13  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => You do not have permission to access this page.
    [code] => 
)

May 07 08:39:13  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

## 1 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php(466): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")

## 2 internal function: CRM_Utils_System_Joomla->permissionDenied()

## 3 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(74): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:0))

## 4 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::__callStatic("permissionDenied", (Array:0))

## 5 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::permissionDenied()

## 6 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Event_Page_EventInfo->run((Array:3), NULL)

## 7 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))

## 8 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

## 9 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(96): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

## 10 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()

## 11 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(405): require_once("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 12 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(380): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 13 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")

## 14 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch()

## 15 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(261): JApplicationSite->doExecute()

## 16 /home/twsc/public_html/index.php(49): JApplicationCms->execute()

## 17 {main}

May 12 23:33:54  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => You do not have permission to access this page.
    [code] => 
)

May 12 23:33:54  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

## 1 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php(466): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")

## 2 internal function: CRM_Utils_System_Joomla->permissionDenied()

## 3 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(74): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:0))

## 4 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::__callStatic("permissionDenied", (Array:0))

## 5 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::permissionDenied()

## 6 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Event_Page_EventInfo->run((Array:3), NULL)

## 7 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))

## 8 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

## 9 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(96): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

## 10 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()

## 11 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(405): require_once("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 12 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(380): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 13 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")

## 14 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch()

## 15 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(261): JApplicationSite->doExecute()

## 16 /home/twsc/public_html/index.php(49): JApplicationCms->execute()

## 17 {main}

May 16 06:09:01  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => You do not have permission to access this page.
    [code] => 
)

May 16 06:09:01  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

## 1 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php(466): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")

## 2 internal function: CRM_Utils_System_Joomla->permissionDenied()

## 3 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(74): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:0))

## 4 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::__callStatic("permissionDenied", (Array:0))

## 5 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::permissionDenied()

## 6 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Event_Page_EventInfo->run((Array:3), NULL)

## 7 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))

## 8 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

## 9 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(96): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

## 10 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()

## 11 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(405): require_once("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 12 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(380): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 13 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")

## 14 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch()

## 15 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(261): JApplicationSite->doExecute()

## 16 /home/twsc/public_html/index.php(49): JApplicationCms->execute()

## 17 {main}

May 17 02:40:13  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => You do not have permission to access this page.
    [code] => 
)

May 17 02:40:13  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

## 1 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php(466): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")

## 2 internal function: CRM_Utils_System_Joomla->permissionDenied()

## 3 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(74): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:0))

## 4 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::__callStatic("permissionDenied", (Array:0))

## 5 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::permissionDenied()

## 6 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Event_Page_EventInfo->run((Array:3), NULL)

## 7 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))

## 8 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

## 9 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(96): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

## 10 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()

## 11 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(405): require_once("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 12 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(380): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 13 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")

## 14 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch()

## 15 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(261): JApplicationSite->doExecute()

## 16 /home/twsc/public_html/index.php(49): JApplicationCms->execute()

## 17 {main}

May 27 00:27:40  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => You do not have permission to access this page.
    [code] => 
)

May 27 00:27:40  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

## 1 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php(466): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")

## 2 internal function: CRM_Utils_System_Joomla->permissionDenied()

## 3 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(74): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:0))

## 4 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::__callStatic("permissionDenied", (Array:0))

## 5 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::permissionDenied()

## 6 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Event_Page_EventInfo->run((Array:3), NULL)

## 7 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))

## 8 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

## 9 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(96): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

## 10 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()

## 11 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(394): require_once("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 12 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(369): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 13 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")

## 14 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch()

## 15 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(265): JApplicationSite->doExecute()

## 16 /home/twsc/public_html/index.php(49): JApplicationCms->execute()

## 17 {main}

May 28 03:55:24  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => You do not have permission to access this page.
    [code] => 
)

May 28 03:55:24  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

## 1 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php(466): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")

## 2 internal function: CRM_Utils_System_Joomla->permissionDenied()

## 3 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(74): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:0))

## 4 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::__callStatic("permissionDenied", (Array:0))

## 5 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::permissionDenied()

## 6 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Event_Page_EventInfo->run((Array:3), NULL)

## 7 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))

## 8 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

## 9 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(96): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

## 10 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()

## 11 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(394): require_once("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 12 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(369): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 13 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")

## 14 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch()

## 15 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(265): JApplicationSite->doExecute()

## 16 /home/twsc/public_html/index.php(49): JApplicationCms->execute()

## 17 {main}

May 30 01:59:07  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => You do not have permission to access this page.
    [code] => 
)

May 30 01:59:07  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

## 1 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php(466): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")

## 2 internal function: CRM_Utils_System_Joomla->permissionDenied()

## 3 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(74): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:0))

## 4 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::__callStatic("permissionDenied", (Array:0))

## 5 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php(80): CRM_Utils_System::permissionDenied()

## 6 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Event_Page_EventInfo->run((Array:3), NULL)

## 7 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))

## 8 /home/twsc/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

## 9 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(96): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

## 10 /home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()

## 11 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(394): require_once("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 12 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(369): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/twsc/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")

## 13 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")

## 14 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch()

## 15 /home/twsc/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(265): JApplicationSite->doExecute()

## 16 /home/twsc/public_html/index.php(49): JApplicationCms->execute()

## 17 {main}

Comment: Can you please check Civi log to get more details about the DB error

Comment: From the error_log file: [28-Apr-2019 22:08:34 America/New_York] PHP Warning: Declaration of CRM_Volunteer_Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL) in /home/[my account]/public_html/media/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Permission.php on line 151

Answer (score 3):

Karen-Ann

This has been fixed by core team, but they haven't done a release. You can apply the patch for the fix from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/477.patch).

Looks like the DB:error is for 'nativecode=1055 ** Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column'. This is also [fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/481), can you please apply the [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/481.patch) from here and try again.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Hi Pradeep, thank you for replying, I appreciate it. I still get the same error when I try to run the report, this is the beginning of the error message  i get now, if i can, I'd send you the log message another way as it is long...  May 28 18:19:20  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16

Comment: Can you add the error to your question

Comment: Error added above to the original question.

Comment: Did you apply the patch which i mentioned in my answer?

Comment: There is 2 patch in my answer, did you apply both of them?

Comment: I applied patches to the following 2 files: permission.php (line 6, line 80) and VolunteerReport.php (line 615)

Comment: What error you getting now?

Comment: CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")
2 internal function: CRM_Utils_System_Joomla->permissionDenied()
3.  And I'm running it as superadmin.  And yes, it is a different error.

Comment: This is a different error

Comment: I applied both patches. Remember i was using CiviVolunteer successfully before doing the Civi upgrade to 5.11.0 which broke CiviVolunteer.